# How can I add a twitter feed to my Java program?

Tags: java, twitter

I'm trying to add a scrolling twitter feed to the bottom of my program. I'm currently using `JFrame` and what not for the GUI of my program.

Later on as I develop the program more and more I would like to add different feed options from different sites or even twitter users/hashtags that are completely customizable by the user. This part is for later on as I am trying to make the basic frameworks of my program right now.

Comment: I don't know how to do specifically what you want, but you will need to use the Twitter API. Docs: https://dev.twitter.com/overview/documentation

Comment: That's a start! Thank you!

Comment: An other point, just try to ask good well-pointed question so that you will find the right and quick answer. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask